# What is the simple closed curve $C$ in Klein bottle $K$ such that $K\backslash C$ is an open Möbius band?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $C$ be a simple closed curve in Klein bottle $K$.
>
> $K\backslash C$ has one component and is homeomorphic to an open Möbius band.
>
> What is $C$?

Comment: Hi, I've tried to give a hint. Perhaps you could say more about what your thoughts are about this question, e.g. how you visualise the Klein bottle and the Mobius band, as that will really help the people who answer your questions! I know you're fairly new to math.SE, but do consider this in future. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at the pictures. Can you cut the Klein bottle along a suitable circle to get the Mobius band?

[image]

Comment: And as a additional hint: remember that all four corners of the square represent the same point in $K$, so that a line on the square connecting any two corners is actually a circle in $K$ !

Comment: You can cut the square horizontally and glue them together.

Comment: But what is the simple closed curve?

Comment: maybe cut through the diagonal?

Comment: To go from a Mobius band to a Klein bottle, you glue the top edge of the Mobius band to the bottom edge. So how do you go from a Klein bottle to a Mobius band?

Comment: @KennyWong We can cut the square horizontally. Then by the identification of the top edge with the bottom edge, we get a Mobius band.

Comment: Yes exactly - we should cut the square along the top edge (which as you say is the same as the bottom edge).

Comment: @KennyWong To get a square, we should cut from the middle point of the left edge to the middle point of the right edge horizontally (since the middle point of the left edge is the same as the middle point of the right)?

Comment: Actually, we CAN cut along the top edge. Notice that all four corners of the square are the same point! So the top edge IS a circle. (The single-headed arrows identify top-left with bottom-left, and identify top-right with bottom-right. The double-headed arrows identify top-left with bottom-right, and identify top-right with bottom-left. So yes, all four corners are the same point!)

Comment: @KennyWong Thanks. And we can cut along the left edge to get an annulus as well?

Comment: Yes, cutting along the left edge (which is the same as the right edge) does indeed give a cylinder, which is the same as an annulus.